# Creatin a minimal macOS app bundle

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to create a minimal app Bundle. I found the following page on apple.com:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html

My Info.plis is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>MYAP</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.myself.myapp</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My executable file is a text file with permissions `-rwxrwxr--` that says:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch ~/Desktop/hello.txt
```

Which I can execute in the terminal.
My folder structure is as follow:

```
MyApp.app/
   Contents/
      Info.plist
      MacOS/
          MyApp
      Resources/
```

So I would expect this application to work. Yet, when I click on it, I get the following message:

> You can’t open the application “MyApp.app” because PowerPC
>   applications are no longer supported.

Does anyone know what this is about? How does the OS decide it this is a PowerPC app?
My OSX version is 10.11.6 (15G1108). I think this was working with 10.11.5

Edit: Added Shebang

Comment: If the one-liner is supposed to be a bash script, it should probably start with a proper shebang. I guess the OS is expecting your executable to look like an executable for Intel CPUs rather than one compiled for a PowerPC or a *fat* binary containing both.

Comment: I replaced the script with a compiled c++ hello world and the problem persists.

Comment: This article may help - it looks like apps can get marked as not being X86-64 compatible and the only thing you can do is reset the Launch Services database using `lsregister` tool... see what you think, I am just trying to help. http://forums.sketchup.com/t/power-pc-error-message-on-macbook-pro/23024/33

Comment: I tried to fix the typos but it won't let me

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Mark Setchell I found what happened:

- On the last update, OSX stopped accepting scripts without a shebang, and marked my app as "Not x86_64"
- When I tried to fix it/ replace the script with a compiled file, the flag was still there

So the solution was to fix my script and move the app to reset the Launch Services database. (Which stores absolute paths)

Comment: Cool - well done! And thank you for sharing back with the community.